# linked list always executing else statement

Tags: java

SoI have this code

```
private void customerRemove(){
   customers = new LinkedList <Customer>();
   customers.add(new Customer(1, "John", 20));
   customers.add(new Customer(2, "Mike", 21));
   customers.add(new Customer(3, "Harry", 22));
    System.out.println("\nRemoving a customer.");
   System.out.print("Enter a customer ID: ");
   int rmvId = In.nextInt();
   for (Customer rmvCustomer:customers){
        if(rmvCustomer.getID()== rmvId){
          customers.remove(rmvCustomer);
            System.out.println("Customer removed.");
            System.out.println(" ");
           break;             
    }
        else{
            System.out.println("That customer does not exist.\n");
            break;

        }
   }}
```

when I call this method. Always else statement is executed first why is this so and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean it is executed first?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: @RyanJ when I give id 2 as a customer id, I get the output That customer does not exist.

Comment: @Samrat See Sandesh Gupta's answer, it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need of `else` part inside the `for` loop. 
In you case you're not waiting to iterate over all the `Customers` before showing on screen that `Id` is not found.

You can keep a `boolean found` variable that you'll set to `true` if `Id` matches. If no match is found, you print it out using the same `found` variable.
Update your code like below:

```
private void customerRemove() {
    customers = new LinkedList<Customer>();
    customers.add(new Customer(1, "John", 20));
    customers.add(new Customer(2, "Mike", 21));
    customers.add(new Customer(3, "Harry", 22));
    System.out.println("\nRemoving a customer.");
    System.out.print("Enter a customer ID: ");
    int rmvId = In.nextInt();

    boolean found=false;
    for (Customer rmvCustomer : customers) {
        if (rmvCustomer.getID() == rmvId) {
            customers.remove(rmvCustomer);
            System.out.println("Customer removed.");
            System.out.println(" ")
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
     System.out.println("That customer does not exist.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your for loop is just iterating once. If customer is found, it will remove. If not found, it goes to else block and breaks the loop, thus it doesn't check further elements in the linked list.

```
   for (Customer rmvCustomer:customers){
        if(rmvCustomer.getID()== rmvId){
          customers.remove(rmvCustomer);
            System.out.println("Customer removed.");
            System.out.println(" ");
           return;             
       }
    }

    System.out.println("That customer does not exist.\n");
   }
```